# Looking for a way to manipulate css in gatsby within function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

So because I'm making a website in Gatsby, I want to make a navbar that appears when clicked on a div. I've made up that function to make sure I can do it in normal html, css and javascript. This is that function :

```
var myNavigation = document.getElementById("navigation");
var toggleStatus = 1;

var myFunction = function (){
       if (toggleStatus === 0) {
       myNavigation.style.display = "none";
       toggleStatus = 1
       } else {
              myNavigation.style.display = "flex";
              toggleStatus = 0;    
       }
};

myButton.onclick = myFunction;
```

But I have no idea to make this work in Gatsby. I've managed to create the click event(with a simple alert tool) but now I have to manipulate the style.display to flex or to hidden, depending what the toggleStatus is, so this status also needs to be changed when clicked.
This is the code I have so far:

```
function showNav(){
}

const Header = () => {
    return(
       <header>
            <p>STIJN REYGAERTS</p>
                  <div className='Icon' onClick={showNav} style={{display: "flex"}}>
                     <div></div>
                     <div></div>
                     <div></div>          
                   </div>
       </header>    
    )
}

export default Header
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many approaches to do this but in many of them, you need to use a state (using `useState` hook). They are a bit different than your provided snippet but much cleaner and readable.

### The first approach, JSX rendering.

```
const Header = () => {
const [toggleNav, setToggleNav]=useState(false)


const showNav=()=> setToggleNav(!toggleNav);

    return(
       <header>
            <p>STIJN REYGAERTS</p>
                  <div className='Icon' onClick={showNav} style={{display: "flex"}}>
                     <div></div>
                     <div></div>
                     <div></div>          
                   </div>
         {toggleNav && <div id="navigation">Your navbar here</div>}
       </header>    
    )
}

export default Header
```

Basically, the snippet above sets a state in a functional component (like your `<Header>`). `setToggleNav` is the triggered function to change and update the value of your state. `toggleNav` will contain your `state`'s value and `useState(false)` is the initial value, `false` in this case.

Every click in `showNav` will toggle the value of `toggleNav` by `setToggleNav(!toggleNav)` (setting the opposite value). Since it's a state, it will re-render your component and if it's true, it will validate this condition `toggleNav && <div id="navigation">Your navbar here</div>` so your navbar will be displayed.

### The second approach, CSS toggling:

```
const Header = () => {
const [toggleNav, setToggleNav]=useState(false)


const showNav=()=> setToggleNav(!toggleNav);

    return(
       <header>
            <p>STIJN REYGAERTS</p>
                  <div className='Icon' onClick={showNav} style={{display: "flex"}}> 
                     If you click me, I'll toggle the class
                     <div></div>
                     <div></div>
                     <div></div>          
                   </div>
         <div id={`navigation`} class={`${toggleNav ? 'is-visible': '' }`}>Your navbar here</div>
       </header>    
    )
}

export default Header
```

Then, in your SCSS/CSS:

```
#navigation{
  display: none;
}

#navigation.is-visible{
   display: block;
}
```

The idea of this approach is almost the same; a state that changes its value by clicking `showNav` but in this case, it sets a class (`is-visible`) that `displays` as a `block` your navbar, since it's validating the ternary condition: `` {`${toggleNav ? 'is-visible': '' }`} ``.

Comment: This comment helped me a lot by understanding how the logic works and how you've set it up. Unfortunately, is my navbar constant visible and a lot of the styling is not shown..

Comment: Thanks @Stef_Verniers, that's the idea! Can you paste the code of what you've tried?

Comment: I've posted it as an answer below this comment!

Comment: I would suggest editing your question, not providing a new answer to avoid confusion. I've edited my answer, there was a mistake with closing brackets in the ternary condition. ``{`${toggleNav ? 'is-visible': '' }`}``. Try it now.

Comment: Apologies, so I've changed my code and I can see that the the state is toggled when clicking on the Icon. But the navbar itself doesn't react to that command. But I think it is because there's a problem with linking the css to the corresponding properties

Comment: I've edited the names of the classes because I'm not comfortable with random hyphens in classnames. So here is is my css:
```#Navigation {
  display:none;
  background-color: red;
}

#NavigationVisible{
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 23;
  background-color: green;
  height: auto;
  width: 100vw;
  font-size: 300vh;
}```

Comment: You are using an ID to change this behavior. I would suggest a class. If the code is toggling the class name, it's a matter of CSS. Just check why is not getting the style. The toggle works.

Comment: Okay, I made it work but now I have one last problem.
I got the header which containes an h1 element and the icon to toggle the navigation but.. When you toggle the navigation in responsive mode, the navigation should pop open below the header and at the moment, it opens inside the header. Any way how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Navbar from '../navbar/navbar'
import navigation from '../navbar/navbar.css'


const Header = () => {
const [toggleNav, setToggleNav]=useState(false);

const showNav = () => setToggleNav(!toggleNav);
  return(
       <header>
            <p>STIJN REYGAERTS</p>
                  <div className='Icon' onClick={showNav}>
                     <div></div>
                     <div></div>
                     <div></div>          
                   </div>
            <div id={navigation} className={`${toggleNav} ? 'is-visible': '' `}><Navbar /></div>       
       </header>    
    )
}

export default Header
```